# The output of my C code is 1 more than the value I expected. Why?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I am tracing a code but the final output that I expected is 1 less than the actual output. Also the return of the function is confusing me. I don't get what it means by return(b+2) in function1. Where am I supposed to add 2??I put the ouput in the comments for clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int function1(int info[], int size, int a, int b)
{
   //info:3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 //size=9 //a=i->1..9 //b=(i-1)*(i-1)
    if (a<5)//1 3 
    {
        info[a]=b-1;//-1 3
        //b=0 4 
        //a=1 ->-1 //a=3 ->3 
        printf("info[%d]=%d\n",a,info[a]);
    }
    else //5 7 9
    {
        info[a]=b+1;//info[a]=17 37 65
        //b=16 36 64 
        //a=5 ->17 //a=7 ->37 //a=9 ->65    
        printf("info[%d]=%d\n",a,info[a]);
    }
return(b+2); //what's happening here?
}
int main()
{
    int info[9],i,j,a,b;
    info[0]=1;

    for (i=1; i<9; i++) 
        info[i]=info[i-1]+2; // 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17
    i=1;
    while (i<=9)
    {
        j = function1(info,9, i,(i-1)*(i-1));
        printf("while:i=%d j=%d\n\n",i,j); //1 2//3 6//5 18//7 38//9 66
        i = i + 2;//1 3 5 7 9
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

```
Expected:
info[1]=-1
while:i=1 j=-1

info[3]=3
while:i=3 j=3

info[5]=17
while:i=5 j=17

info[7]=37
while:i=7 j=37

info[9]=65
while:i=9 j=65
```

```
Actual:
info[1]=-1
while:i=1 j=2

info[3]=3
while:i=3 j=6

info[5]=17
while:i=5 j=18

info[7]=37
while:i=7 j=38

info[9]=65
while:i=9 j=66
```

Comment: The most useful tool in such a cases is the debugger.

Comment: These variable names are next to useless. What this code does is far from clear. You've even gone so far as to call it `function1` which is utterly devoid of meaning.

Comment: What is the specification of what it should do?

Comment: As it stands now, the solution can be "subtract one before printing".

Comment: @tadman I didn't write the code. I am just tracing it. The question asked to find the output that's it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I haven't learned how to use a debugger in class yet.

Comment: I doubt you will be taught that in the class. This is something you need from day zero when learning to program.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the question asked what the output of this code should be. It didn't say anything else.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't get what you mean by subtract one before printing.

Comment: Whatever they're trying to teach you I'm not sure. Pop this into a debugger and step through it. That's the only way to understand it if you don't know by reading.

Comment: Or add 1.  Your title says the problem is the opposite of what is in the body.

Comment: @stark I am really sorry. I meant the other way. I fixed my question now. I can't change the code. My question is to trace the code. I didn't write the actual code itself.

Comment: @tadman so you can't explain where my tracing went wrong? Idk how to use a debugger.

Comment: I can't do any better than a debugger can, sorry.

Comment: @tadman thanks for trying tho. I don't have enough time to learn how to use a debugger at this moment but thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you do. You're going to spend 10x more effort manually debugging this code than the 30 minutes it will take to open this up in a debugger. Visual Studio Express, XCode, and Eclipse all have debugger support built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what I was doing wrong. I just need to add 2 with b to get the j values because function1 says to return(b+2). The values of info[a] aren't the actual output.